# Flask.json_encode, TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting started with flask. I'm trying to return some json from a flask app which I want to generate from a dictionary:

My code looks like:

```
resp = views.calculate(d)
print type(resp)
print resp
return Flask.json_encoder(**resp)
```

The output:

```
<type 'dict'>
{'target1': 'DOES NOT EXIST', 'stage': 0, 'token': u'fsdfsdf', 'target2': 'DOES NOT EXIST', 'text': ''}
```

and finally I get The error above. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Flask.json_encoder`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.json_encoder) is the *class* used to encode JSON with. It does not accept keyword arguments, nor would calling it produce JSON directly.

To produce a response with JSON encoded data, use [`flask.jsonify()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.jsonify) instead:

```
from flask import jsonify

return jsonify(**resp)
```

If all you need is the JSON string, use [`flask.json.dumps()` here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.json.dumps), passing in the dictionary (and not keyword arguments):

```
from flask import json

return json.dumps(resp)
```

In both cases the class referenced by `Flask.json_encoder` (via the `app` instance) would be used to produce the JSON encoding.

Comment: Thank you , I ended up going with return jsonify(**resp)